# Trying to get a single json object android

Tags: android, json

Would really apreciate if someone can help me out here. Trying to get "full_name", "Sex" and "location" if "full_name" is "John" but not working

```
public class DataParser  extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer>{

Context c;
ListView lv;
String jsonData;

ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<Person> persons=new ArrayList<>();

public DataParser(Context c, ListView lv, String jsonData) {
    this.c = c;
    this.lv = lv;
    this.jsonData = jsonData;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Parse");
    pd.setMessage("Parsing...Please wait");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.parseData();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    pd.dismiss();
    if(result==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        //CALL ADAPTER TO BIND DATA
        CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(c,persons);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

 private int parseData()
{
    try {
        JSONObject ja= new JSONObject(jsonData);
        persons.clear();
        Person s=null;

        JSONObject jo=ja.getJSONObject("full_name");

        if (jo.equals("John")) {

            int id = jo.getInt("id");
            String name = jo.getString("full_name");
            String sex = jo.getString("sex");
            String location = jo.getString("location");

            s = new Person();
            s.setId(id);
            s.setFull_name(name);
            s.setSex(sex);
            s.setLocation(location);

            persons.add(s);
        }
                return 1;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
}
```

Would really apreciate if someone can help me out here. Trying to get "full_name", "Sex" and "location" if "full_name" is "John" but not working

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: @CaspainCaldion getting unable to parse. edited the post to show complete class

Comment: post full error and if possible the json file

Comment: Please provide the JSON(sample with same structure) file you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you have a JSONArray of person and you want to get the object that has person = John.

If the data is like this

```
[{
    "full_name": "John Smith",
    "sex": "male",
    "location": "New York, NY, United States"
}, {
    "full_name": "Angela Johnson",
    "sex": "female",
    "location": "San Diego, CA, United States"
}]
```

You can write:

```
JSONArray people = new JSONArray(jsondata);

int index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < people.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject tmpObj = people.getJSONObject(i);
    string name = tmpObj.getString("full_name");
    if (name == "John") {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

JSONObject johnObjExample = people.getJSONObject(index);

string johnName = johnObjExample.getString("full_name");
int id = johnObjExample.getInt("id");
String name = johnObjExample.getString("full_name");
String sex = johnObjExample.getString("sex");
String location = johnObjExample.getString("location");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer however i keep getting the first column only

Comment: Its working fine now when i changed the "==" to ".equals". Thanks alot. U saved me 2 days of work